# mkdir() not creating folder on the website

Tags: php

my php code is not creating the final folders which are (profile,post and cover) when hosted online but creates when hosted locally.Here is the code please help

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['file']) && ($_POST['file']=='Upload'))
    {
        $path = "fh_users/Male/".$user."/Profile/";
        $path2 = "fh_users/Male/".$user."/Post/";
        $path3 = "fh_users/Male/".$user."/Cover/";
        mkdir($path, 0, true );
        mkdir($path2, 0, true);
        mkdir($path3, 0, true);

        $img_name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $img_tmp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $prod_img_path=$img_name;
        move_uploaded_file($img_tmp_name,"fh_users/Male/".$user."/Profile/".$prod_img_path);

        mysql_query("insert into user_profile_pic(user_id,image) values('$userid','$img_name')");
        header("location:Secret_Question1.php");
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Did you maybe forget to paste the code? There isn't any in your post :-)

Comment: be careful when you ask your question, your code block was not indented properly so nothing was shown...

Comment: this is my code

Comment: first you **must not** use `mysql_xxx` functions which are deprecated since many years and completely removed from newer php versions. Have a look at `mysqli` or `PDO`. Then, for your mkdir problem, do you have write permissions in the folder you are trying to create a directory ?

Comment: Probably the hosting online has some restrictions that prevents your script to run mkdir commands or you don't have permissions for that/these folders.

Comment: i have allowed all permissions

Comment: the problem is that it is creating half directory...its creating upto users then leaving the profile,post and cover not created

Comment: Add to the top of your script and try again, report back any errors: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Also remove the trailing slash on those directories when you try to make them.

Comment: I'm not seeing where `$user` or `$userid` are defined; you're also trying to create directories with **no** permissions on them (which you *might* get away with on Windows)? There are also some security implications with creating web-server read/writeable files/directories under the docroot which you'd be advised to address.

Comment: @CD001 yeah... I sure hope `$user` is a strict, whitelisted and controlled variable! And `$prod_img_path` needs to be cleaned and sanitized to the teeth (never ever a good idea to use user-supplied filenames when saving files on a server).

Answer (score 0):

the second parameter of the [`mkdir()`](http://php.net/manual/function.mkdir.php) function is the permissions.

using `mkdir($path, 0, true );` you create a new folder with `000` permissions (ie no permissions for anybody)

you should use `mkdir($path, 0750, true );` instead which will give full permissions to the owner, read/execute permissions for group users and nothing for unknown users

- *The execute permission on a directory allows the affected user to enter the directory, and access files and directories inside*

Comment: Be interesting to see, if any dirs *have* been created, whether they can actually be deleted :) As an aside, there's almost no reason, in a web server environment, to ever allow *nobody* any permissions for anything - 750 would do it.

Comment: @CD001 you're right, I edit my answer. if a folder is created with 000 permission, it can be deleted if the user has write and execute permissions to the parent directory

Comment: has worked with this mkdir($path, 0755, true ); for male side but doesn't work on female side